# VBA - Dictionary search - type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, type-mismatch

So I'm learning how to use Dictionaries but I have encountered a type problem. In the code below I get an error.

> Type mismatch

Each time I try to call `If Not target.SearchItem(sKey) Is Nothing Then`. I want it to return a object then if it isn't `Nothing` I can convert it back to long.

```
For Each target In dList.getArray
    For Each key In aList.getArray(1).getKeys
        sKey = CStr(key)
            'Error occurs here - as Type mismatch
            If Not target.SearchItem(sKey) Is Nothing Then
                cData.setData(sKey) = CLng(target.SearchItem(sKey))
                target.removeData = sKey
             Else
                 'if value doesn't exists it will just be 0
                  cData.setData(sKey) = 0
              End If
    Next key
Next target
```

`data` is my dictionary that is in a separate class:

```
Property Get SearchItem(name As String) As Variant
    If data.exists(name) Then
        'becomes a Variant/Integer - data(name) is a Variant/long
        Set SearchItem = CVar(data(name))
    Else
        'Should return Nothing if item doesnt exist
        Set SearchItem = Nothing
    End If
End Property
```

Update: To explain the problem I bit more. Even though I return it as a variant it will still be partly Integer and therefor If Not `target.SearchItem(sKey) Is Nothing Then` will return mismatch as it needs an object and VBA doesn't read is as a variant or something. Is there anything like Nothing, null or equally that works for a long? That would solve the problem.

This code below returns a long as I want it to, but I can't use -99 as it would corrupt the data analyse. It needs to be something that isn't a value

```
Property Get SearchItem(name As String)
    If data.exists(name) Then
        SearchItem = data(name)
    Else
        'SearchItem = Nothing
         SearchItem = -99
    End If
End Property
```

Comment: Not really enough code there for us to do a quick debug. Though someone may spot easily what is wrong.

Comment: @QHarr It occurs at " If Not target.SearchItem(sKey) Is Nothing Then" It returns a integer/long if value exists and it cant check if it's nothing. Is there any value like nothing that works for long?

Comment: What kind of dictionary are you using?

Comment: @TinMan I'm using Private data As Scripting.dictionary if that's what you mean?

Comment: Is it possible that sKey = CStr(key)  is the source of the problem? I set up a test case with a string I knew was in the dictionary (i added it in the class initialize) and it ran fine.

Comment: I don't think you can use `Set` to assign an integer, so the property will fail when there is an integer in the dictionary. Perhaps use `SearchItem = data(name)`.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code because you wrapped the dictionary.  I susupect that changing `aList.getArray(1).getKeys` to `aList.getArray(1).getKeys()` will solve the problem.

Comment: @TinMan That sounds promising!

Comment: @QHarr That is not the problem unfortunately. As an input to SearchItem I take a string, key is currently a variant that I need to convert.

Comment: I just realised that when looking at Zev's answer.

Comment: @ZevSpitz That will solve the error but the problem is that if the item doesn't exist I don't want to return any valid number.

Comment: @Fredrik So in that case, return `Nothing`. Either one can be returned if the property type is `Variant`.

Comment: @TinMan VBA will automatically remove () if no argument is given.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I think so too but it doesn't work

Comment: But sKey is  a string, no? If passing an Int in you would get ByRef type mismatch at signature level.

Comment: Can we see your declarations as well?

Comment: And if you do Debug.Print TypeName(key) what are you handling?

Comment: You have your class set up wrong.  It would be better to test if the item exists then to return nothing from the search.  The Search should only use `Set` if it is returning an `Object`.  If you don't mind emailing it to me I will review your design.  If it was a working example I would recommend posting it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Qharr yes, sKey is a String. I'm using a string because I got no integer values as keys for the dictionary. Any specific declaration? Key is a String but when using it directly I get ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: @TinMan How do you mean? So if an item exists I should return Nothing? If I understand correctly I shouldn't return the value until I have received if the value exists? Unfortunately I can't share the code at the current state due to company/school rules.

Answer (score 1):

1. `If Not target.SearchItem(sKey) Is Nothing Then`

   - This implies that the stored item is an Object
2. `cData.setData(sKey) = CLng(target.SearchItem(sKey))`

   - The only way that this line will work on an Object is that the Object has a default value that can be converted to long.  If the Object's default value is returning a value that can be converted to long.

Does `Clng(Object)` work on the actual Object that is being stored in the Dictionary?

If you are storing mixed data type then `SearchItem` check if the return data is an Object.

```
Property Get SearchItem(name As String) As Variant
    If isObject(data(name)) Then
        Set SearchItem = data(name)
    Else
        SearchItem = data(name)
    End If
End Property
```

I would not convert the datatype in this method. I would instead create one or more separate methods or convert the data type at the point of use.

> ```
> Function getTypedItem(Key as Variant, DataType as VbVarType) as Variant
> ```

IsNumeric(Obj)

Since you are using actual Keys of the Dictionary we know that it will return something and there is not a need for `.Exists` in this context.  What you will need to do is test if it is returning an Object before you test whether the `Object Is Nothing`.

```
If IsObject(Target.SearchItem(sKey)) Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.SearchItem(sKey)) Then
        cData.setData(sKey) = CLng(Target.SearchItem(sKey))
    End If
ElseIf IsNumeric(Target.SearchItem(sKey)) Then
    cData.setData(sKey) = CLng(Target.SearchItem(sKey))
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `Set` to assign an integer, so the property will fail when the dictionary item is an `Integer`. Perhaps use:

```
Property Get SearchItem(name As String) As Variant
    If data.exists(name) Then
        'becomes a Variant/Integer - data(name) is a Variant/long
        SearchItem = data(name)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VBA does not have nullable primitive types such as a nullable Long. A usual workaround is to use a Variant, which can be assigned the value of Empty and which can also hold a Long natively.

I would rewrite your property as follows:

```
Property Get SearchItem(name As String) As Variant
    If Data.exists(name) Then
        SearchItem = Data(name)
    Else
        SearchItem = Empty
    End If
End Property
```

And the test for empty would be:

```
If Not IsEmpty(target.SearchItem(sKey)) Then ...
```